# is the icon (*.icns) part of executable?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icons

In cocoa application, Is ICON file part of deliverable?  I have inserted the icon file into project and set the icon name in the .plist file. Just I want to know that ICON file is the part of deliverable. If we run the executable in any other mac os, the ICON will appear or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The icon file is within your app bundle, as is the executable and the .plist file. Check in the Resources folder in the app bundle to make sure that the icon file is copied into the bundle during building.